# Is it proper to say "at lesser cost"?

Tags: american-english, phrase-usage

Would it proper to use *"at lesser cost"* in the following phrase:

> Get better outcome at lesser cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sense is in agreement with @kjo:

**lower cost**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/110672?redirectedFrom=lower%20cost#eid38933829)

> S1. Forming comparative adjectives corresponding to special uses of
>   low adj., as lower-cost

As in:

> "Get a better outcome at a lower cost."

Your use of **at lesser** is not un-grammatical, but **at lower** is better usage.